# How to get rid of the "Walkthrough / First Steps side panel" in trial orgs

Tags: force.com, administration

We are starting an implementation for a new client on a trial org. I'm confronted with an very annoying side-panel which as an unfortunate also overrides the force.com admin-panel. It looks like this:

[image]

**How to get rid of this and restore normal behavior with the force.com admin-panel like that?**

[image]

Googled already without success... Possibly I'm using the wrong keywords to find it...

Comment: just wondering if it is a browser extension or injected via any of the home page components?

Comment: @RajivBhatt - no, it's not injected stuff. It's quite vanilla Salesforce official standard and supposed to help newbies. But it's a real burden for veterans and I'm looking for a kill-switch.

Answer (score 2):

Salesforce Technical Support can do this - so you have to log a case.

Comment: If by trial org, they mean developer org then no, Salesforce Support will not help you.

Comment: @dphil Question does appear to be about a trial org. However, if they're a partner, it would seem they should be looking for support through the partner community on this issue and it would be an issue related to the template they're using for the trial org.

Comment: @crmprogdev Potentially, they don't really state that in the question.  I'm not the one who gave the -1 though.  I always feel awkward commenting on an answer/question that someone else downvoted.

Comment: It's in title of the question. That walk thru also never appears in a DE Org. Further, look at top right tab in first screen-shot where it shows "salesforce free trial disable panel" in the google search tab. Finally, I'm absolutely confident that @UweHeim who asked the question knows the difference between the two.

Comment: @crmprogdev Ya, I wasn't very observant.

Comment: Not sure what all your comments are about. However I just had the walk through side panel removed for two Trial Org's (not DE) by Salesforce Support today so I can confirm that Salesforce helped out with this (the company I work for is a SF Partner). And this is what obviously Uwe Heim was looking for, as far as a native German speaking person I understood from his post.